# “mvn dependency:tree” Return could not resolve dependencies for project com. * was cached in the local repository……

Tags: java, maven

When I execute “mvn dependency:tree”，error：“Could not resolve dependencies for project com.*.*-*:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find *:*:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in http://*.com/libs-snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interva”
[image]

Via google，I see before I execute this command，execute "mvn clean install" can solve this problem.
But I want to Know why?
Is it necessary to download all dependent packages to local when exporting ependency-graph?

Comment: It needs to download the poms to be able to determine which transitive dependencies are needed. So yes those are needed.

Comment: Do not post pictures of code or errors, simply paste them in the formatted block `like so`. It will make it easier on you to remove your information, and to anyone else to find the similar error using search. [meta-question on this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)